# What is the Iso electric point of the given amino acid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph, amino-acids

[image]
I am not sure about three but for two acidic parts we take the mean of the two..  But what about three?

Comment: Thank you for editing! I have removed the comment, and upvoted your question. If you receive a useful answer, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/333867) it. A recent overview of isoelectric point calculation techniques has been published along with a database. It is available [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkw978); L. P. Kozlowski. 'Proteome-*pI*: proteome isoelectric point database'. *Nucleic Acids Research*, ($2017$), 45, D1, D1112$-$D1116. Hopefully someone more competent will provide a summary. Good luck, and [welcome!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Though in the current case it's more straightforward; apply the definition of isoelectric point, consider raising the pH from $0$. Everything is protonated, and there is a positive charge. When you raise pH, the right-hand side group is first to deprotonate. Thus $$pI = average(2; 4).$$

Comment: Thank you very much@Linear Christmas. I am using a smartphone and am unable to find the "accept" option.. It would be very kind of you if you could tell me where to find it..

Comment: Sure you would have found it if there were one in this case ;). I only provided comments (which are not really intended as answers on SE) because I thought it would be a good idea to provide an answer that also deals with isoelectric points of peptides and longer chains. Might post an answer later on but I would have to go through the literature which will take time. Until then, stick around the site and you are sure to find lots of interesting content. As always, glad I could help!

Comment: Chatting requires a minimum of $20$ [reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/333867)  on any SE site (see [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) for an overview). Don't be discouraged, I am sure you'll reach $20$ in no time. You can still listen in on existing chatrooms; the main English chemistry chatroom can be found [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).